# C# compiler - getting verbose output or diagnostic info

Tags: c#, csc, .net-7.0, verbose

Is there an option to the C# compiler CSC.exe which generates more verbose output, specifically details on its parsing logic?

I've got a C# source file in a project which essentially contains this:

```
namespace lib.data.files
{
  public class group
  {
    public file[] file;
  }
  public class file
  {
  }
}
```

And a compile error of

```
files.cs(5,15): error CS1031: Type expected [lib.data.csproj::TargetFramework=netstandard2.0]
```

The problem can be fixed by changing line 5 to

```
public lib.data.files.file[] file;
```

But I'm curious to find out what the CSC compiler thinks `file[]` represents (if it isn't picking up the class referrence in the same namespace).

(p.s. adding `<ErrorLog>compiler-diagnostics.sarif</ErrorLog>` to the project file only gives the same level of detail.)

(p.p.s. this compile error only showed up after upgrading from .NET 6.0 to .NET 7.0)

Comment: How do you build the project?

Comment: Note that CSC.exe can't compile for Net6/7 - so your question should probably be asking for something else.

Comment: `file` is a new contextual keyword in C# 11 (.NET 7) that modifies the visibility of a type (like `public`, `private`, etc.) so it may be seeing it as an additional modifier, rather than the type name. Type names in C#/.NET generally start with an uppercase letter, which would avoid the issue. More details on file-scoped types and the `file` keyword here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/file

Comment: @Iridium, you nailed it.  I appreciate the help.  Thank you!